# EMMIXskew package can not be downloaded

Tags: r, install.packages

I want to install the EMMIXskew package in r for creating clustered scatterplots. While it was removed from the CRAN repository, it should still be available via the archive.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/EMMIXskew/index.html

I have tried to install the package with the following code,

```
# Download package tarball from CRAN archive

url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/EMMIXskew/"
pkgFile <- "EMMIXskew_1.0.3.tar.gz"

download.file(url = url, destfile = pkgFile)

install.packages(pkgs=pkgFile, type="source", repos=NULL)

unlink(pkgFile)
```

but this resulted in an error.

```
> url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/EMMIXskew/"
> pkgFile <- "EMMIXskew_1.0.3.tar.gz"
> download.file(url = url, destfile = pkgFile)
trying URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/EMMIXskew/'
Content type 'text/html;charset=UTF-8' length 1482 bytes
==================================================
downloaded 1482 bytes

> 
> install.packages(pkgs=pkgFile, type="source", repos=NULL)
Error in getOctD(x, offset, len) : invalid octal digit
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘EMMIXskew_1.0.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
> 
> unlink(pkgFile)
```

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: Try `url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/EMMIXskew/EMMIXskew_1.0.3.tar.gz"
` to download the tar.gz file